# Any drivers for Cisco Linksys AE2500 USB wifi adapter?

Tags: wireless, drivers, cisco

This has been asked before, but is there not some sort of simple driver you can install in the terminal to make it work?

Comment: You can't tell just by model name. Give output of lsusb with the adapter plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Windows XP drivers from [CISCO](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-product/?pid=01t80000003KVW1AAO) and save the `.inf`,`sys` and `bin` files.
2. Download [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/) and extract it with: `tar -xvf ndiswrapper-xxx` (replace xxx to match your downloaded file).
3. Change to the directory created by tar: `cd ndiswrapper-xxx`
4. Execute the following commands one after the other:

   ```
   make
   make install
   ndiswrapper -i drivername.inf 
   ndiswrapper -l   ## to verify the installation---should show the driver(s) and device ID> 
   modprobe ndiswrapper
   ```

Reboot and see if there's any change.

If you have an old installation of `ndiswrapper`, you might want to remove it before starting all the above step.

Refer to this article: [Installing cisco linksys AE2500 wireless adapter in Linux](http://www.grailbox.com/2012/05/installing-cisco-linksys-ae2500-wireless-adapter-in-linux/)

Comment: I've heard of this, but I was looking for something a little better since I heard that your internet will probably be pretty unstable if you use this method. Do you know of anything else?

Comment: Certain drivers in Ubuntu can be installed with `ndiswrapper` only. As far as I know this will not significantly affect the performance (but yes, it is nice to have an 'official' driver). Sorry, I do not know of any other methods.

Comment: It keeps telling me there's no such file or directory when I do cd ndiswrapper. And I extracted with archive manager if that works for tar -xvf because it said there wasn't a file or directory for that either,